# Proof of limits at infinity

Tags: calculus

> Say $p(x) = a_nx^n+...+a_0$ where n is odd and $a_n$ positive
>
> a) Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}p(x)= \infty $ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}p(x)= -\infty$
>
> b) Prove that $\exists c ∈ R$ such that $p(c) = 0$

For part a) I have that $p(x) = x^n(a_n+...+\frac{a_0}{x^n})$

Can I immediately assume that $\lim_{x\to\infty}p(x)= \infty $ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}p(x)= -\infty$?

For part b) I assume that I have to use the Intermediate Value Theorem, so as soon as I proof the part a) this will be a consequence.

Comment: Well, you must explain why the limit of the part within parentheses is $\;a_n\;$ ...

Comment: So  limits are assertions ;o)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is correct from

- $p(x) = x^n(a_n+...+\frac{a_0}{x^n})\to\pm \infty$ as $x\to \pm \infty$

since $\forall i\implies \frac{a_i}{x^{n-i}}\to 0$

by contnuity of $p(x)$ and IVT we can deduce that exists $c$ such that $p(c)=0$.

Comment: Thanks, I feel silly to post the question and answer but it seemed a little wrong for me

Comment: @Juju9704 It's a legitimate doubt, and your idea was correct.